# CakePHP 2.1 validating multiple select boxes

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using CakePHP 2.1 and i have two models Movie and Person.. Where Movie contains person_id as foreign key as multiple select boxes.. So how to validate person_id in Movies view add function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type of validation need?
add this code to the movie model:

```
public $validate = array(
    'person_id' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
        ),
    )
);
```

more on validation: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html